# Is it a good idea to integrate SeerSuite and a visualization engine, such as Stefaner's Relation Brower?

Tags: web-applications, actionscript

I would like to link a set academic papers based on which papers they cite, which papers cited them, the topic areas (and keywords) they contain, and the examples they use for applied work.  I expect I'll need a web infrastructure backend like [SeerSuite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeerSuite) and I'd like to couple this with a visualization engine like Moritz Stefaner's [Relation Browser](http://moritz.stefaner.eu/projects/relation-browser/).  However, I don't know any Actionscript / Flare which Relation browser uses.  I've certainly used the ****seer products, but I haven't really messed around with the backend.

Is this a reasonable approach?  Are there alternatives I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relation Browser is currently being ported to AS3 using the Flare framework, at present, its jsut AS1, which will be problematic in Flex/Flash Builder (you'll have to use a very old Flex SDK)

You could also use Flare directly. Flare uses GraphML (is an XML formatted file) to set up nodes and links between them, this is what I used, but it was shitty difficult to generate this file type programatically (there are no tools to help you do so) From what I read, SeerSuite also produces JSON, which Flare can also handle.

I suggest firstly getting the SeerSuite up and running, and produce some Json output. Download Flash Builder (as recommended by Flare), and at least get the Radial Graph working with Flare.

Before chosing the Visualisation method, have a look at http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/, loads of projects, with details of the Code base they used.